Unable to call Shopify API's based on store_name and confusion on domain retrieved from webhook headers
I created a Shopify app in which I used to get shop details using GraphQl API
"shop": {
  "name": "Qa_Testingd",
  "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
  "id": "gid://shopify/Shop/1",
  "myshopifyDomain": "qa-testingd.myshopify.com",
  "url": "https://qa-testingd.myshopify.com"
}

Based on this response I used to identify from which store this webhook is received and based on the name in shop resource, I used to call Shopify APIs but it is not working
According to following resolved issue
https://community.shopify.com/c/webhooks-and-events/in-webhook-order-create-how-do-we-identify-from-which-store-the/td-p/589829
X-Shopify-Topic: orders/create
X-Shopify-Hmac-Sha256: XWmrwMey6OsLMeiZKwP4FppHH3cmAiiJJAweH5Jo4bM=
X-Shopify-Shop-Domain: johns-apparel.myshopify.com
X-Shopify-API-Version: 2019-04

I check that if the myShopifyDomain from the shop resource and domain from the webhook headers is equal then do something.
Customers can have their own custom domains, then the domain which is coming from webhook headers, will it be equal to the domain that is myShopifyDomain in shop?
And the Shopify APIs based on shop name resource is not working. It gives not found error.
